# Error with importing 'train model from_config' from 'deeppavlov.core.commands.train'

Tags: python, machine-learning, import, nlp, importerror

```
import json
#from deeppavlov.core.commands.infer import build_model_from_config
from deeppavlov.core.commands.train import train_model_from_config
from deeppavlov.download import deep_download

PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH = 'deeppavlov/configs/ner/ner_ontonotes.json'
with open(PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH) as f:
    config = json.load(f)
train_model_from_config(PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH)
ner_model = build_model_from_config(config)
ner_model(['Computer Sciences Corp. is close to making final an agreement to buy Cleveland Consulting Associates'])
```

I am following along a [tutorial](https://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/0.0.7/components/ner.html) but the import for deep pavlov is giving me trouble. Have already installed the library on my vm.

The error message is as follows:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-a6e1af262d62> in <module>
      1 import json
      2 #from deeppavlov.core.commands.infer import build_model_from_config
----> 3 from deeppavlov.core.commands.train import train_model_from_config
      4 from deeppavlov.download import deep_download
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'train_model_from_config' from 'deeppavlov.core.commands.train' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/commands/train.py)
```

[screenshot of code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIE96.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're linking a documentation for version [`0.0.7`](https://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/0.0.7/components/ner.html) while the latest stable version is [`0.7.1`](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/0.7.1/features/models/ner.html).

Now building and using the pretrained OntoNotes NER model can be done like this:

```py
from deeppavlov import build_model, configs

ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes, download=True)
ner_model(['Computer Sciences Corp . , El Segundo , Calif . , said it is close to making final an agreement to buy Cleveland Consulting Associates'])
```